# Difference between Nginx from nginx.org repo or epel repo?

Tags: nginx

I was trying to install ngingx from the epel repo on RHEL7.1 and was running into errors regarding missing packages.

the nginx version on the epel repo is 1.6.3-8.

I then tried to install nginx from the nginx.org stable repo and it seems to have installed fine but is 1.10.0-1.

My questions is what is the difference between the two, if any? Are they different branches?

Comment: Nginx.org will always provide the latest version. It's maintained by nginx.org. Epel repo may not always have the latest version of nginx as it needs to pass the update policy that can be seen at https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL_Updates_Policy . That said both should install correctly. If you post the errors here, someone might help you to get it sorted out. Also there are only two braches of nginx. Mainline and stable version. Please see... http://serverfault.com/q/715049/102173

Comment: Building Nginx is surprisingly easy, though then you have to download source and build each time you want an update. It gives you more flexibility though https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-2-setting-up-aws-for-wordpress-with-rds-nginx-hhvm-php-ssmtp/#nginx-source