# Is it safe to include upstream Nginx in unattended-upgrades?

Tags: nginx, unattended-upgrades

My company has Nginx deployed from [upstream's repositories](https://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#Ubuntu). I would ideally like to include this repository in unattended-upgrades, but I'm concerned that this will break things at some point.

I understand that this carries the risk of bugs, which is a tradeoff I'm willing to make, but what's unclear to me is whether Nginx has any kind of configuration syntax/semantics backwards compatibility guarantee (we don't use third party modules so this is the only kind of backwards compatibility I care about). I've read [What’s the difference between the “mainline” and “stable” branches of nginx?](https://serverfault.com/questions/715049/what-s-the-difference-between-the-mainline-and-stable-branches-of-nginx) and the [linked blog post](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-1-6-1-7-released/) but didn't see anything. Even if I use the stable repository, it seems that when mainline is forked and merged with stable I'm still risking breakage in the absence of a stability promise. Is that interpretation correct? Or am I missing some Nginx policy somewhere or possibly even approaching this problem completely incorrectly?

Comment: JFYI, from the version 1.20 nginx switches from PCRE to PCRE2 library (but I don't know if PCRE2 is 100% back compatible with PCRE syntax or not).